# Count Number of Elements From a DISTINCT query

Tags: php, mysql, count, distinct, where-clause

I have this tbl_transactions, this is the table
[image]

the image is the result after querying

```
SELECT DISTINCT vehicle_type_name, vehicle_plate_number FROM tbl_transactions
```

[image]

now, I need to count the number of 2 Wheeler, 4 Wheeler, etc... can someone help me to this. I've used the combination of DISTINCT and WHERE clause, but it shows error in query.

Comment: You want to [GROUP BY](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) `vehicle_type_name`.

Comment: do you mean... I will GROUP BY after I query the DISTINCT ?

Comment: No, you must use `COUNT(DICTINCT vehicle_plate_number)`

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vwi9bkdUVPoZeURdNAEoDX/2

Comment: The tutorial, I linked to, explains in detail how it works. Did you read that?

Comment: @ErgestBasha I've got the result I wanted to, but what if the table is not yet use a distinct query, like the 1st image

Comment: @KIKOSoftware im trying to understand sir, but i don't get it ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select in a subquery only the distinct values and count it on the outer query. If this is what you are trying please try and let me know if it helps and feel free to ask if something is unclear.

```
SELECT vehicle_plate_number,count(*) as number_of_rows
FROM (
       SELECT vehicle_type_name,
              vehicle_plate_number
       FROM tbl_transactions
       GROUP BY vehicle_plate_number,vehicle_type_name
) as t1 
GROUP BY vehicle_plate_number;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vwi9bkdUVPoZeURdNAEoDX/4

Comment: Hey, Ergest, I've edited your code, and finally I got the expected result I wanted, I just rename the column names on your, to be exact on mine, here is the link (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vwi9bkdUVPoZeURdNAEoDX/5)... I'm curious what the function inside the FROM

Comment: thanks again Ergest, God bless and always keep safe :)